# Pass Value from Controller to a class asp.net MVC3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Controller which is receiving value as an output parameter from the database and I want that value to be passed to a .cs page created and use that value there.Can U please help me to know how can i Pass the value from controller to class.
Thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the controller you could instantiate the class and invoke some method on it by passing the value you retrieved from the database as parameter:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string value = ... // retrieve the value from database

    // instantiate the class
    SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();

    // call some method and pass the value
    someClass.SomeMethod(value);

    return View();
}
```